# Mysql checksum for data only

Tags: mysql, migration, checksum

I have some groups of two tables, each group table having the same structure. (dev & prod server)
Their data will never change from user action, only from admin when a change occurs.

I want to make sure that data inserted in my fields is identical from dev to prod, without noise like server version, timestamps of anykind, autoincrements...

I made a little query using md5 and group_concat, instead of checksum, because I need to skip some fields, and also I was not sure about how deep is checsum (like, does it compare also auto-increment state..? etc...)

Then I saw that group_concat has a default character limit of 1400.
Some Text fields contains very long strings (about 200 000 characters).

Increasing this limit from 1400 to more than 200 000 sounds a bit like a bad idea, but I would like your advice considering this :

- My actual query is : `SELECT md5(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS("", '.$fields.'))) FROM '.$table`
- I'm looping this query on about 20 tables
- tables can have from 3 to 20 fields of any kind (tinyint, text, date) and any length

So :

- What do you think about this query + a big fat `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 900000;` ?
- Do you have an alternative to checksum regarding my doubts ?

Comment: What about `SELECT crc32(sum(crc32(CONCAT_WS("", '.$fields.')))) FROM '.$table`? both `md5()` and `crc32()` are not very strong, but that does not matter for your case and `crc32()` returns a number so it may be summed. You may even leave the outer call and use the sum as your checksum.

Comment: Thanks, smart advice ! I started with group_concat because I needed the real string to use in a diff function in case of checksum mismatch. But I'll just make a separate query.

Comment: You can do "per-column" checksums too to know where to look specifically. Or just `select ... into outfile` and diff the resulting csv files.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  Use Percona's `pt-table-checksum`.